# Failed to update data using CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite, core-data

I wrote a Mac App to generate my sqlite file, then I copy it to my iOS App.

When I want to change some data in iOS App, I found the changes can't be saved.

The error is: `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134030`

Code for create sqlite On Mac:

```
NSManagedObjectModel *mode = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelPath];
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:mode];

NSDictionary *options = @{
                          NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption : @YES,
                          NSSQLitePragmasOption: @{@"journal_mode":@"DELETE"}
                          };

[coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:sqlitePath options:options error:nil];

NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator;
managedObjectContext.undoManager = nil;

[managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
    for (ClipCard *currentCard in self.allCards)
    {
        ClipItem *clipInfo = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ClipItem" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

        clipInfo.clipName = currentCard.clipName;
    }

    [managedObjectContext save:nil];
    [managedObjectContext reset];
}];
```

Code for read and change on iOS:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator == nil)
    {
        _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:self.managedObjectModel];

        NSURL *storeClipData = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"ClipItems" withExtension:@"sqlite"];

        NSDictionary *options = @{
                              NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption : @YES,
                              NSSQLitePragmasOption: @{@"journal_mode":@"DELETE"}
                              };

        [_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeClipData options:options error:nil];
    }
    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

//fetch data
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"ClipItem"];
fetch.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;

NSError *error = nil;
self.clipItems = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];

//change some
if ([self.managedObjectContext hasChanges])
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
    NSLog(@"save error: %@", error);
}
```

Hope I have made myself clear, any help will be appreciated?

BTW, I have no idea why my stack overflow account can't login, so I sign up a new one.

Comment: You are trying to write to a database in the application bundle, which is read only.  You need to copy the sqlite file into a read/write folder, such as the Documents folder, using NSFileManager then open the database from there.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it and tried but failed, will do it again. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing happened, some error 134030